# XMLRPC call error

Tags: php, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I'm having problem during XMLRPC call. The code is following:

```
$msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
    "contact.search",
    array(
        //Set user id
        new xmlrpcval($tableID, "int"),
        new xmlrpcval(
        array(
            "email"=> new xmlrpcval($searchEmail, "string"),
        ),"struct"
    )
));

$response = $xmlrpc->send($msg);
var_dump($row);
var_dump($response);
```

When call happens, I get following error message (var_dumped):

```
public 'val' => int 0
  public 'valtyp' => null
  public 'errno' => int 2
  public 'errstr' => string 'Invalid return payload: enable debugging to examine incoming payload xmlrpc element I8 cannot be child of VALUE' (length=111)
  public 'payload' => null
  public 'hdrs' =>
```

Value of `$tableID=3`.
Value of `$searchEmail="exampl@fooo.com"`

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has same problem should download updated version of xmlrpc.inc library on [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpxmlrpc/bugs/86/) link.

Cheers!